# CUresult vs cudaError - how to get readable error descriptions?

Tags: cuda

I want to get a human readable description of result returned by cuInit. Every single page I've found recommnend using cudaGetErrorString for this purpose, but this results in error:

```
error: cannot convert CUresult {aka cudaError_enum} to cudaError_t 
{aka cudaError} for argument 1 to const char* cudaGetErrorString(cudaError_t)
```

What's the difference between CUresult and cudaError and what function can I use to interpret the former?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
LIBRARY         RETURN TYPE     VALUES
CUDA Driver     CUresult        enum cudaError_enum    in cuda.h
CUDA Runtime    cudaError_t     enum cudaError         in driver_types.h
```

The CUDA Runtime provides the function cudaGetErrorString to convert a cudaError enum value to a string.

The CUDA Driver API does not provide a function to return string.

The error names and values for CUresult and cudaError_t do not match.

NVIDIA does not currently supply a library for returning an error string for CUresult. It should only take a few minutes to convert the data in cuda.h into a function.

Comment: See Kratz' answer below, this is actually added in a recent CUDA driver release.

Answer (score 14):

The current driver API as time of writing *does* support translating an CUresult to its string representation and description.

From the [Driver API doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__ERROR.html):

> ```
> CUresult cuGetErrorName ( CUresult error, const char** pStr )
> ```
>
> Gets the string representation of an error code enum name.
>
> ```
> CUresult cuGetErrorString ( CUresult error, const char** pStr )
> ```
>
> Gets the string description of an error code.

Comment: Is there anything special that one need to do to have those functions working - when I include `cuda.h` compiler cannot find symbol `cuGetErrorString`? I using CUDA 6.0, which should be good enough, am I right?